# C# Winforms application secure connection to Access DB

Tags: c#, winforms, desktop-application, .net, eazfuscator

I have a C# 2010 **Winforms** application that uses OleDb to connect to an Access 2010 database which is password protected. **This is not an online application!**

I currently store the password in plain text in the connection string [I know this is horribly insecure] which is obfuscated using [Eazfuscator.NET](http://www.gapotchenko.com/eazfuscator.net). I am interested in a way to securely store the password in such a way that it cannot be obtained by decompiling or any other practical methods.

I am aware that there are methods to do this for ASP.NET applications by encrypting the connection string in app/web.config but it would not work for me since my application is a desktop application.

So far I didn't find any method to achieve this.

Here is what I have thought of doing:

Request a password from the user, since there will be only one user who will have access to the database. Get a hash (SHA1 / SHA512) for the input password, select a certain number of characters from the hash, salt it, add it to the connection string and try to connect.

Obviously, if the user would forget the password, there would be absolutely no way to gain access to the database other than by using brute force.

**Is there any way to store the password used in the connection string in the program so that it cannot be obtained by any practical means?**

Comment: Why not just use the user's password directly?

Comment: Because he would probably use a password that would be very vulnerable to a dictionary attack.

Comment: But if you're just protecting a more complex password using a simpler password, that won't do any good.  (Unless you're trying to defend against people who have the database but not the config)

Comment: Yes but my program can be nasty if he tries to brute-force his way through my application (I am thinking of shutting the computer down or deleting the database / program). Even if he just copies the algorithm to generate passwords in valid forms through a dictionary attack, it would take far more time than just inputting it directly. This would decrease the practicality of a dictionary attack while imposing no noticeable performance issues on the user. Either way, this approach leaves the user with no means of recovering the password if he forgets it, which is what I am trying to avoid.

Answer (score 1):

You should generate a long random secure password for the database, then encrypt it using the `ProtectedData` class.
This will encrypt it using the user's Windows logon password, so that it will be impractical to read it unless the user is logged on.

Comment: I have two questions regarding this approach:

1. If the bad guy gains access to the victim's laptop and logs on his account, couldn't he gain access to the password by analyzing the application?
2. Could the client use the program on another computer?

Comment: I think that you are in a dead way here. Everything you put in the application could be reversed. It's just a question of time and tools available. Security by obfuscation is not security. For the second question I think the answer is NO, to the best of my knowledge the ProtectedData cannot be used to Unprotect using a different User Profile. But I'm waiting the experts to come here very fast.

Comment: Well then that would be even worse than my idea since he would completely lose access to the database if the computer died (he does back-up the database). Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a DSN and store the username and password there, rather than in the app, but then any app that knows the DSN can use the database and the credentials are available in the registry in plain text.

What are you trying to defend against, the app getting into the wild? The database? An unauthorised user sitting at the machine?  The password has to live somewhere...

Comment: The most important thing is protecting the database from any kind of unauthorized access. I am most interested in preventing a user that manages to copy the database and the program from accessing the database. Also, if the laptop is stolen, I want no practical way for the thief to be able to access the DB. I know all this might sound paranoid but given the nature of the information stored, I can take no chances.

Comment: Then you can not have the password stored on the laptop, you need to ask the user for it (or some variation).  Another option is not to store the database on the laptop, (maybe use a network drive), so the thief doesn't get the database.

Comment: So then there is no way of storing the password in the program in a way that the user cannot find it out, right?

Comment: If the program knows the password then the thief with the laptop can use the program to access the data...  If you don't want the thief to get at the data, either the password or the database (or both) must not live on the laptop.